# mysql_connect() fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have a problem, when I write my welcome.php I need to use `mysql_connect()` but when I run it, an error appears:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/u781677053/public_html/cas/welcome.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/u781677053/public_html/cas/welcome.php on line 4
```

I'm using a web called Hostinger.es, not apache, or any stuff

The code:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","u781677053_lo","987654") or die();
mysql_select_db("u781677053_po") or die();
```

Comment: `mysql_*` is now deprecated . Use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`.

Comment: Get the *real* error `or die(mysql_error())` and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Anant you are a hero man! mysqli_* worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_*` is now deprecated . Use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`

You can do it like below in `mysqli_*`:-

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","u781677053_lo","987654","u781677053_po") or die(mysqli_connect_error());
```